# Generalized eigenspace - Construction algorithm proof

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, jordan-normal-form, nilpotence, generalized-eigenvector

Suppose that $A$ is an $n\times n$ nilpotent matrix.

Let $x_1,\ldots,x_m$ be eigenvectors of $A$ forming a basis for the eigenspace of $A$.

For $j=1,\ldots,m$, form a Jordan chain $$C\left(x_j\right)=\left\{v_{j,1},\ldots,v_{j,k_j}\right\}$$ by "going backward", that is, start from the eigenvector $v_{j,1}=x_j$ and iteratively solve $$Av_{j,k}=v_{j,k-1}$$ while the system has a solution (until you find a system that has no solution).

Several sources I found on the web, as well as an old textbook, seem to suggest that $$C=C\left(x_1\right) \cup \ldots \cup C\left(x_m\right)$$  is a basis for the generalized eigenspace of $A$, that is, for the null space of $A^n$, without offering a formal proof that the algorithm works. How would you prove that? Any reference would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If $A$ is nilpotent and complex, then the entirety of $\mathbb{C}^n$ is its generalized eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue 0. Therefore, any basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ is a basis of the generalized eigenspace. So, what do you want to do?

Comment: Actually, this holds even for other fields than ℂ.

Comment: Here we are looking for a basis having a particular structure, that is, a basis of Jordan chains. We are not trying to prove that a basis of Jordan chains exists, which is proved in  virtually all linear algebra textbooks. What we want to prove is that a particular algorithm for finding bases formed by independent Jordan chains actually works.

Comment: "until the system has a solution" do you mean until the system has _no_ solution? Also, what part of the construction is unclear? Each chain is a Jordan chain by construction. Do you have a more precise version of the algorithm?

Comment: It means that $A v_{j,k_j} = v_{j,k_j-1}$ has a solution while $A v_{j,k_j+1} = v_{j,k_j}$ has no solution. Yes, indeed each chain is a Jordan chain by construction. What is not clear is that the union of all Jordan chains (one for each eigenvalue) is a basis. I think that the algorithm as stated is already very precise: you loop through eigenvalues, you build a chain for each of them, and then you take the union of the chains.

Comment: Sorry I meant one Jordan chain for each eigenvector. Of course there is only one eigenvalue, equal to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach does not work. Consider the matrix
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}
$$
with eigenvectors $\pmatrix{1\\1\\0}$ and  $\pmatrix{1\\-1\\0}$. None of them is in the range of $A$, only their sum is.

Instead  one has to work from the other direction: Assume $A^dv=0$ but $A^{d-1}v\ne 0$. Then $(A^{d-1}v \dots Av,v)$ are linear independent and part of the Jordan basis. A reference for this approach is the book by Axler.

Comment: The counter-example is perfect and as simple as it gets. The final remark however does not add new information about the method used to construct a single chain, as the last generalized eigenvector of the proposed chain is an ordinary eigenvector.